# Dart - Unit test for exception in constructor

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I write some simple project in Dart (1.9.3) with unit tests using `unittest` library. I have a problem with checking if constructor throws an error. Here's the sample code I write for this issue purposes:

```dart
class MyAwesomeClass {
    String theKey;

    MyAwesomeClass();

    MyAwesomeClass.fromMap(Map someMap) {
        if (!someMap.containsKey('the_key')) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid object format');
        }

        theKey = someMap['the key'];
    }
}
```

and here are the unit tests:

```dart
test('when the object is in wrong format', () {
    Map objectMap = {};

    expect(new MyAwesomeClass.fromMap(objectMap), throws);
});
```

The problem is the test fails with following message:

```
Test failed: Caught Exception: Invalid object format
```

What do I do wrong? Is it a bug in `unittest` or should I test exceptions with `try..catch` and check if exception has been thrown?
Thanks for all!

Comment: Recommend reopening because it isn't immediately obvious from the "duplicate" topic how to apply it to constructors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can test if the Exception has been thrown using:

```
    test('when the object is in wrong format', () {
       Map objectMap = {};

       expect(() => new MyAwesomeClass.fromMap(objectMap), throws);
    });
```

passing as first argument an anonymous function raising the exception.